# Convert 'UnsafePointer<CChar>' in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm  trying to convert Objective-C code to Swift. 
When that I convert this line it gave me an error:

line Objective-C code:

```
self.bike.isLocked = result.isLocked ? YES : NO;

self.bike.lastReturnTime = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:result.return_time];
```

line Swift converted code:

```
 bike?.isLocked = result.isLocked ? true : false
 bike?.lastReturnTime = String(utf8String: result.return_time)
```

and line two error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8)' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<CChar>' (aka 'UnsafePointer')

`isLock` type is `Bool`
and `lastReturnTime`  type is `String`

Can you help me?

Comment: Please show the code for declaration of the variables

Comment: thank MartinR and @Venkadesh :) .